# JHipster v7.1.0 - How to create docker-compose conf with dev profile

Tags: docker-compose, jhipster

I can't find any documentation on how to create a custom docker-compose configuration for multiple applications having **dev-profile**, as in https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#docker-compose-subgen#Generating a custom Docker-Compose configuration for multiple applications

My microservice architecture consist of one gateway and one microservice and I create those with a jdl-file. When the docker-compose sub-generator runs, it creates a configuration (docker-compose/docker-compose.yml) with
**SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,api-docs** and database conf for prod.

I have try running '**./mvnw -ntp -Pdev verify jib:dockerBuild**' but nothing is changed in the mygateway/src/main/docker/app.yml nor in docker-compose/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how my gateway folder looks like (only the important files):

```
/gateway/src/main/docker/
     | central-server-config/localhost-config
       | application.yml
     | app.yml
```

And this is how I created a working docker-compose with dev-profile:

1. Rebuild project; `mvn clean install`
2. Rebuild docker image with dev profile; `./mvnw -ntp -Pdev verify jib:dockerBuild`
3. Copy the src/main/docker/app.yml to src/main/docker/app-dev.yml
4. In the file **app-dev.yml** change the following

- In services.<my_gateway>.environment

  From

> - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,api-docs
> - SPRING_R2DBC_URL=r2dbc:postgresql://<your_gateway_name>-postgresql:5432/<database_name>
> - SPRING_LIQUIBASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://<your_gateway_name>-postgresql:5432/<database_name>

To

> - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,webapp,api-docs
> - SPRING_R2DBC_URL=r2dbc:h2:file://tmp/h2db/db/<database_name>;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
> - SPRING_LIQUIBASE_URL=jdbc:h2:file://tmp/h2db/db/<database_name>;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

Also I removed the hole part of the postgress-container (its not needed)

***FYI***: The default db location is relative. In the container the relative path on init is the root folder, where appuser may not create directories. Since I use '**/tmp/h2db/db**'

5. In the **application.yml** I change the following

From

> ```
> eureka:
>   client:
>     service-url:
>       defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/
> ```

To

> ```
> eureka:
>   client:
>     service-url:
>       defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka/
> ```

**FYI**: The configuration is telling configserver clients the wrong eureka url via the overrides section. Remove it or just use the same as in the EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE, I did the last.

Then I can start the gateway with dev-profile without any errors.
e.g.

> docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app-dev.yml up

I have not test it yet, but it should work creating a **docker-compose/docker-compose.yml** with dev-profile using the same/similar changes as above.